# I can't register to Ubuntu one. The captcha images are not authorizing my input although I'm sure I have it right

Tags: ubuntu-one

For a few hours, I've been trying to register with Ubuntu One in the Software Center.

When I do come across a captcha that I can read, I'll input it into the registration form and immediately I'm told that I've inputted the wrong numbers for the captcha.

I was able to register through a windows machine, but entering that information into the Ubuntu One log in screen does not work.

Finally, I believe there is a problem with the captcha authentication system that you guys use. I know I've inputted the correct numbers at least 15 times in the three hours that I've been struggling with the registration process. I'm sure myself and others trying to register through that registration method would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 12):

This is a known issue. A user filed a bug report about it ([Launchpad Bug #1033598](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1033598)) in August 2012. Unfortunately, the bug has a low "heat score" and therefore does not attract much attention. The heat score would increase if more users confirmed that they were affected by the bug. There is a Catch-22, however, because you have to log in to Launchpad in order to confirm a bug, and Launchpad uses the Ubuntu One login, and setting up an Ubuntu One login is the very problem at issue....

**You can work around this issue** by registering on the main Ubuntu One login page, which does not require a Captcha. The procedure is:

1. Go to the main Ubuntu One login page (https://login.ubuntu.com/).
2. Click “I am a new Ubuntu One user.”
3. Enter your email address.
4. Enter your name.
5. Enter your password (twice).
6. Click the checkbox to accept the Ubuntu One terms of service.
7. Click “Create Account.”

I would recommend that, as soon as you have registered with Ubuntu One, you visit Launchpad Bug #1033598 (link above) and confirm the bug to raise its heat level. Doing so would help attract attention to the bug and, one would hope, get it resolved for future users. You could then go back to the "Ubuntu Single Sign On" window that the Ubuntu Software Center raised when you clicked "Turn On Recommendations" button, then click the link to "Log-in with my existing account."

Comment: Upvoted *and* raised the heat level...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I tried going trough the website after not being successful in ubuntu and this is where I got!

[image: not able to create account]

update: so I was finally able to login using insecure password. But I get same thing when I try to use more complicated one.