# Ubuntu Software Center fails on every captcha I try

Tags: software-center

I am trying to turn on the recommendations in the Ubuntu Software Center.
When trying to sign up it keeps putting up captchas.
I can't read any of them!
There is not a button for audible prompting.

I have "old eyes" and clicked refresh for different captcha but can't read a one of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: post image of one, I will try to read them for you :D

Comment: @MiHa: not funny when you can't read captchas... **:P**

Comment: @Fabby it wasn't meant offensively ;)

Comment: I too faced same "captcha" problem, I suggest: create account at [login.ubuntu.com](https://login.ubuntu.com/one-redirect) and use "user name" and password in software center.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of "[I can't register to Ubuntu one. The captcha images are not authorizing my input although I'm sure I have it right](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632976/i-cant-register-to-ubuntu-one-the-captcha-images-are-not-authorizing-my-input)"

I posted an answer there, but I don't have the rep to close this one.

Comment: You can not close the question, but you still can flag it as duplicate (requires 15 reps), so high-reputation users (3000+ I guess) acting as moderators can find it, and handle it. See:  https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges